# How to create Invoice

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

```
SELECT        
    dbo.PaymentMaster.Code,
    dbo.PaymentMaster.OrderNo, 
    dbo.PaymentMaster.CustIssueNo, 
    dbo.PaymentMaster.Amount, 
    dbo.CustomerMaster.CustName, 
    dbo.OrderRequestMaster.ORequestQty, 
    InvoiceMaster.SGST,
    InvoiceMaster.CGST,
    InvoiceMaster.SGST,
    InvoiceMaster.SubTotal,
    InvoiceMaster.TotalAmount
FROM 
    dbo.CustomerIssueMaster,
    dbo.PaymentMaster,
    dbo.CustomerMaster,
    dbo.OrderMaster, 
    dbo.OrderRequestMaster, 
    InvoiceMaster 
WHERE (dbo.PaymentMaster.CustIssueNo = dbo.CustomerIssueMaster.CustIssueNo
     OR OrderMaster.OrderNo = PaymentMaster.OrderNo) 
    AND OrderRequestMaster.ORequestNo = OrderMaster.ORequestNo
```

I want to create invoice where all conditions should be match but I didn't get any row when there is one row which should be given as result.

I got this result from payment master. and I want customer info, order request info , order info and payment info in invoice master with invoice master field i.e `Code, InvoiceNo, CustNo, InvoiceDate, SubTotal, CGST, SGST, TotalAmount`.

```
Code  PaymentNo     OrderNo       CustIssueNo    PaymentMode PaymentStatus Amount PaymentDate InvoiceNo InvoiceDate
4     KCS[P][00004] NULL          KCS[CI][00001] Cash        Paid          500    14:28.3     NULL      NULL
5     KCS[P][00005] KCS[O][00001] NULL           Cash        Paid          2000   22:33.9     NULL      NULL
6     KCS[P][00006] KCS[O][00002] NULL           Cash        Paid          2000   40:38.1     NULL      NULL
```

I got this results

Comment: **Side Note**: Always use *explicit join* syntax instead of old comma based joins.

Comment: This is non ansi compliant syntax, and a cross join on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

Without any data we are going to be very hard pressed to help.  You say one row should meet criteria, but it is very hard to see how only one record would be returned unless your tables have only one record!

I note from your query that you want CustName, without including CustomerMaster in your WHERE clause - this will lead to trouble!

Please use the following code in a query window and add any missing fields that are important.  Then create some INSERT lines to populate.  Re-post this so that we can help you with a query that does what you want:

```
declare @CustomerIssueMaster table
(
CustIssueNo int
)
declare @PaymentMaster table
(
Code int,
PaymentNo varchar(50),
OrderNo varchar(50),
CustIssueNo varchar(50),
PaymentMode varchar(50),
PaymentStatus varchar(50),
Amount decimal (18,2),
PaymentDate datetime,
InvoiceNo int,
InvoiceDate datetime
)
declare @CustomerMaster table
(
CustName varchar(50)
)
declare @OrderRequestMaster table
(
ORequestQty int,
ORequestNo int
)
declare @InvoiceMaster table
(
SGST decimal(18,2),
CGST decimal(18,2),
SubTotal decimal(18,2),
TotalAmount decimal(18,2)
)
declare @OrderMaster table
(
OrderNo int
)



INSERT INTO @PaymentMaster VALUES(4, 'KCS[P][00004]', NULL, 'KCS[CI][00001]','Cash','Paid',500,'2014-03-28', NULL, NULL)
INSERT INTO @PaymentMaster VALUES(5, 'KCS[P][00005]', 'KCS[O][00001]', NULL, 'Cash','Paid',2000,'2014-03-28', NULL, NULL)
INSERT INTO @PaymentMaster VALUES(6, 'KCS[P][00006]', 'KCS[O][00002]', NULL, 'Cash','Paid',2000,'2014-03-28', NULL, NULL)

SELECT * FROM @PaymentMaster
```

EDIT

Please note I have amended the structure of @PaymentMaster and given three INSERTs to mimic the data you show from SELECT * FROM PaymentMaster, with one exception: I do not understand what format your PaymentDate is supposed to be.  The first two looked like times, but the third cannot be.  I just stuck in a dummy date instead.

Now will you please do the same for the other tables? I have shown you the format you need to use.

Comment: didn't use custname bcz there is no custno in paymentmaster.

Comment: Do you mean custissueno?

Comment: Please can you do as I ask?  Otherwise I do not see how to help you.